# SwiftData - Delete List Item When Cell View Clicked from Different Struct

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I am trying to build To-Do app such as [Microsoft To-Do App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-to-do/id1212616790).

[image]

There is **Row Cell View**(Checkbox and Text horizontally) and **Custom Checkbox Toggle Style View** for the List.

I want to delete Item of **clicked Cell View** but I couldn't organize "**sharing Index**"

**Content View:**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
  @Query(sort: \Note.title) var noteList: [Note]

  var body: some View {
    List {                  
      ForEach(noteList, id: \.id) { item in
        NoteCell(myNote: Note(title: item.title, desc: item.desc))
          .sheet(isPresented: $showEditNoteSheet, content: {
            EditNoteSheet(noteTitle: item.title, noteDesc: item.desc)
          })
      }
      .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
        for index in indexSet {
          deleteItem(index: index)
        }
      })
    }
  }
 
  func deleteItem(index: Int){
    context.delete(noteList[index])
  }
}
```

**Note Cell View:**

```swift
struct NoteCell: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
  var myNote: Note
    
  @State var isChecked = false
  @State var noteSheet = false
    
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      noteSheet.toggle()
      //Delete action here?
    } label: {
      HStack {
        Toggle(isOn: $isChecked) {
        }
        .toggleStyle(iOSCheckboxToggleStyle())
                 
        Text(myNote.title)
      }
      .foregroundStyle(.black)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $noteSheet, content: {
      AddNoteSheet(noteTitle: myNote.title, noteDesc: myNote.desc)
    })
  }
}
```

**CustmIOSCheckBoxToggleStyle:**

```swift
struct iOSCheckboxToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    // 1
    Button(action: {        
      // 2
      configuration.isOn.toggle()
      // Delete action here?
    }, label: {
      HStack {
        // 3
        Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
        configuration.label
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to remove items that have been checked?

If so, there is a way for SwiftData to do that for you. Assuming that each `Note` has an `isChecked` property, you can add a filter so that only unchecked properties are listed:

```swift
@Query(
  filter: #Predicate { $0.isChecked == false },
  sort: \Note.title
) var noteList: [Note]
```

Then in your `NoteCellView`, the quickest way is to use the `Note`'s `isChecked property in your action:

```
struct NoteCellView: View {
  // mark your note as Bindable
  @Bindable var note: Note

  var body: some View {
    // ...rest of view omitted...
    Toggle(isOn: $note.isChecked) {
    // ...etc...
  }
}
```

When you check the toggle, the note object updates, and SwiftData should automatically remove it from the Query collection - and that in turns removes the note from the list.

You may want a bit more of a sophisticated UI – for example, in reminders apps it's not uncommon to delay the removal for a while, giving the user a chance to uncheck the box if they checked it in error. In that case, you may want to keep the `isChecked` state on the toggle, and use some form of cancelable task that is triggered to run after a certain amount of time (say, 2 seconds). After that delayed start, you'd set `note.isChecked = true` in code. If the user unchecks the box in that task, you cancel the task so the underlying `Note` isn't marked as complete after all.

In this option, you don't need to make `Note` @Bindable because you're only going to change it through code, not by binding it to a view. This would make your `NoteCellView` look something like this:

```swift
struct NoteCell: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
  var myNote: Note
    
  @State var isChecked = false
  @State var noteSheet = false
  @State var markNoteCompleteTask: Task<Void, Error>?

  var body: some View {
    Button {
      noteSheet.toggle()
      //Delete action here?
    } label: {
      HStack {
        Toggle(isOn: $isChecked) {
        }
        .toggleStyle(iOSCheckboxToggleStyle())
                 
        Text(myNote.title)
      }
      .foregroundStyle(.black)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $noteSheet, content: {
      AddNoteSheet(noteTitle: myNote.title, noteDesc: myNote.desc)
    })
    .onChange(of: isChecked) {
      if isChecked {
        markNotCompleteTask = Task { @MainActor in
          try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
          try await Task.checkCancellation() // don't continue if the task was previously cancelled
          withAnimation {
            note.isChecked = true
          }
        }
      } else {
        // if isChecked is now false, cancel the task
        markNoteCompleteTask?.cancel()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As long as the `@Query` in `ContentView` still filters to show only notes that are not checked, after 2 seconds the note will smoothly disappear.